# Keep getting mode name when switching buffers in Emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer, elisp, major-mode

I have strange thing in my Emacs and I can't locate it, everytime I switch a buffer I get message with major mode name even when I call the function I get `minibuffer-inactive-mode`

The only global function (for all modes) in my .emacs file (I think) is this:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                      (if (not (memql (intern (major-mode))
                                                      '(fundamental-mode
                                                        erc-mode
                                                        text-mode
                                                        sql-mode)))
                                          (local-set-key (kbd "RET")
                                                         'new-line-and-indent-fix))))
```

How to find the place that add this annoying thing? What different hook can be executed on each mode?

Comment: Does that happens with "emacs -q"?  If so, does it happens with "emacs -Q"?  If "emacs -q" removes this, I would suggest to do a "binary search" with your configuration file (selectively evaluating portions of it until you find the culprit).

Comment: `major-mode` is not a function, so in the code you quoted you want to replace `(intern (major-mode))` with `major-mode` (since the value of `major-mode` is already an interned symbol).

Comment: What is the annoying message that you see? Have you tried `grep`ping for that message in the source code that you use?

Comment: @Stefan it seams that major-mode is a function and a variable.

Comment: @Draw the message is the value of major-mode variable. I can't grep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `major-mode` function in vanilla Emacs. Whatever that function is in your config, it's probably responsible for displaying the message you're seeing.

You want to fix your code (as per Stefan's comment), but you probably also want to look into that non-standard function:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `major-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Yea, I have `(defun major-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (message (symbol-name major-mode)))` in my functions.el. Tanks

Comment: I would get rid of that function -- it looks like it was written so you could check the current buffer's mode symbol with `M-x major-mode RET`, but you can trivially do the same thing with `M-: major-mode RET`, so there's really no need for it.

Comment: In addition, `message` returns `nil` always, so the value will not be the value of variable `major-mode`.  (Not to mention that the value of that variable is a symbol anyway, so it does not need to be `intern`ed.)  In sum, this code is misguided in more than one way.